# Constraint or Trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm pretty much a newbie when it comes to Sql Server, and I have a question as to how to constrain data in a table.

I have 2 fields, which are both bit fields. Any one or both must be set to true but both cannot be set to false.

Is this a constraint or it is the job of a trigger?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a check constraint

```
CREATE TABLE T
(
B1 BIT NOT NULL,
B2 BIT NOT NULL,
CHECK (B1 = 1 OR B2 =1)
)
```

These are more light weight than triggers.

Using triggers would require the construction of the `INSERTED` and `DELETED` pseudo tables in `tempdb` and a query against this.

Check constraints also fire earlier and (in the event of failure) the update/insert does less unnecessary work that needs to be rolled back.

Answer (score 0):

You should use constraints, triggers are (mostly) used to perform actions, rather then pure validation task.